# Differential equation : $t²y''(t)-2ty'(t)+2y(t)=t^4\cos(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $t^2y''(t)-2ty'(t)+2y(t)=t^4\cos(t)$?

Comment: $t$ and $t^2$ are solutions

Comment: I do not know how to find the homogeneous solution. How is the characteristic equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the homogeneous, and trying solutions of the form $y=t^k,$ we get $y'=kt^{k-1}$ and $y''=k(k-1)t^{k-2}.$ So, $$t^2k(k-1)t^{k-2}-2tkt^{k-1}+2t^k=0$$

$$\Rightarrow k(k-1)-2k+2=0.$$ Now, find $k.$

Answer (score 1):

Outline:  This is an Euler equation.  Try the a solution of the form $y = t^r$ in the homogeneous equation.  After you plug it in, you can cancel all $t$'s and you have a quadratic in $r$.  The two solutions for $r$ give you two solutions for the homogeneous equation.  Then use variation of parameters to find a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 0):

For Euler equation take $t=e^x$, so
\begin{eqnarray}
t^2y''&=&\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{dy}{dx}\\
ty'&=&\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\end{eqnarray}